# How to enable Safari ITP Debug mode

Tags: safari

I'd like to force Safari to mark one of my domains as tracker with new ITP 2.0.
I followed the guide here https://webkit.org/blog/8387/itp-debug-mode-in-safari-technology-preview-62/

Since the new Technology Preview version (66) doesn't have ITP Debug mode I've used normal Safari 12.0 on macOS Mojave. After enabling ITP Debug mode and restaring Safari I don't see anything in logs as the guide suggest nor does setting

```
defaults write com.apple.SafariTechnologyPreview ResourceLoadStatisticsManualPrevalentResource example.com
```

have any effect (even with Safari instead of SafariTechnologyPreview). Do I need to change any other Safari or OS settings?

Comment: Same problem on High Sierra (10.13.6) / STP 66

Comment: Looks like we need to wait for version #67: https://twitter.com/johnwilander/status/1047093563442352130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to get Safari Technology Preview 63 download link (https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/STP/091-99601-20180815-01EC2FD2-85EB-11E8-AB5B-AEA972136C40/SafariTechnologyPreview.dmg) via InternetArchive, ITP Debug mode works there.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Jakob. That helped me. To clarify your link, that version is only for OSX Mojave. Build 62 for High Sierra is available here: https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/STP/091-95878-20180801-01EC2FD2-85EB-11E8-AB5B-AEA972136C40/SafariTechnologyPreview.dmg

Answer (score 0):

On newer version of Safari Technology Preview, or inside Safari 13.1+, you should use these updated steps for enabling debug, because the labels have changed: https://webkit.org/blog/9521/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-3/

It says Catalina, but they also work for Mojave.